# Handle and tracking the javascript errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, dom-events

I would like to handle and track Javascript errors in my web app.

The idea is to catch any unexpected error, hide it for the user and track it in order to have a "crash report".

This is not for programming/debugging, instead of that is for final user control.

I was doing some approach using `window.onerror` and sending this to Google Analytics as an **event**, but Is out there any service, plugin or anything else to handle that?

Comment: with chrome you can try `debugger;`, did you try it?

Comment: But I want to handle and track errors in user's browser, not mine.

Comment: now your question is clearer :D

Comment: Sorry, I rephrase my question

Answer (score 1):

I recommend http://jslog.me service

It can catch whole console output in addition to errors and stack traces, works with large JSONs as native Chrome console, and supports offline mode for phonegap/cordova devices.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit and I found that one, looks promising: http://jserrlog.appspot.com/

Depending by your needs there are a lot of paid solutions:

- http://www.muscula.com/
- http://trackjs.com
- https://errorception.com/
- https://rollbar.com/
- https://www.getsentry.com/for/javascript/
- https://www.atatus.com